# Conditional filtering in a multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm attempting to conditionally remove rows (per the `Symbol` index) in a multiindex (if `Limit` equals 1), then keep it removed for the following days until column `Reset` for said Symbol equals 1.
The `Limit` defines how many symbols are allowed for said `Date`.
Limit is the same for each `Date` while Reset is per `Symbol`.

If there's a way to do this without looping over groups, it would be most preferable. I'd also appreciate suggestions on methods on how to approach this.

Generate the df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

np.random.seed(55)
symbols, symlen =   2, 3
times =             np.arange(datetime(2021, 1, 5), datetime(2021, 1, 15), timedelta(days=1)).astype(np.datetime64)
tlen =              len(times)
A, Z =              np.array(['A', 'Z']).view('int32')
symbol_names =      np.random.randint(low=A, high=Z, size=symbols * symlen, dtype='int32').view(f'U{symlen}')
limit =             np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=symbols*tlen, dtype='int32')
end =               np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=symbols*tlen, dtype='int32')
times =             np.concatenate([times] * symbols)
names =             np.array([y for x in [[s] * tlen for s in symbol_names] for y in x])
value_col =         np.random.randint(low=40, high=60, size=len(times), dtype='uint32')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': value_col, 'Limit': limit, 'End': end}, index=[names, times])
df.index = df.index.set_names(['Symbol', 'Date'])
df['Limit'] = df.groupby('Date')['Limit'].transform('sum')-1

groups = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol']).sum()
```

Current result:

```
                    Value   Limit   Reset
Date        Symbol          
2021-01-05  FXF     58      0       1
            NHI     49      0       0
2021-01-06  FXF     50      0       0
            NHI     52      0       1
2021-01-07  FXF     40      0       1
            NHI     52      0       1
2021-01-08  FXF     50      0       0
            NHI     53      0       1
2021-01-09  FXF     43      1       0
            NHI     49      1       1
2021-01-10  FXF     47      0       0
            NHI     41      0       0
2021-01-11  FXF     58      0       0
            NHI     53      0       1
2021-01-12  FXF     41      1       0
            NHI     58      1       0
2021-01-13  FXF     59      0       0
            NHI     56      0       1
2021-01-14  FXF     53      0       1
            NHI     53      0       1
```

Desired output:

```
                    Value   Limit   Reset
Date        Symbol          
2021-01-05  FXF     58      0       1
            NHI     49      0       0
2021-01-06  FXF     50      0       0
            NHI     52      0       1
2021-01-07  FXF     40      0       1
            NHI     52      0       1
2021-01-08  FXF     50      0       0
            NHI     53      0       1
2021-01-09  FXF     43      1       0
2021-01-10  FXF     47      0       0
2021-01-11  FXF     58      0       0
            NHI     53      0       1
2021-01-12  FXF     41      1       0
2021-01-13  FXF     59      0       0
            NHI     56      0       1
2021-01-14  FXF     53      0       1
            NHI     53      0       1
```

Comment: if you dont' mind, kindly regenerate your data, and add `np.seed`, to make it reproducible

Comment: Good idea, fixed.

Comment: kindly check your output again; i do not think it is right. `2021-01-09  FXF     43      1       0
` shouldn't be there. same for `2021-01-12  FXF     41      1       0
2021-01-13  FXF     59      0       0
` unless my interpretation of the logic is wrong

Comment: They should be there because Limit of 1 implies one Symbol is allowed, so FXF remains while NHI is removed. The order of what gets removed is unimportant.